# How to pass multiple conditions to python peewee's join's on argument?

Tags: python, peewee

I was wondering how to do the following SQL query in peewee.

```
SELECT
    farmers.fruit_count,
    vendors.fruit_count,
FROM
    farmers
INNER JOIN
    vendors
ON
    farmers.location = vendors.location
AND
    farmers.alliance = vendors.alliance
AND
    farmers.fruit_count > 0
```

Is ON-AND-AND-... even doable in peewee?  There is not much documentation regarding the `on` argument.  Must I resort to `where()`?  I would assume the query would look something like the following, assuming the `on` argument takes the same form as what `where()` takes:

```
Farmers.select(Farmers.fruit_count,
               Vendors.fruit_count)
       .join(Vendors,
             join_type=JOIN.INNER,
             on=(Farmers.location == Vendors.location,
                 Farmers.alliance == Vendors.alliance,
                 Farmers.fruit_count > 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use & to join the conditions:

```
on=((Farmers.location == Vendors.location) &
    (Farmers.alliance == Vendors.alliance) &
    (Farmers.fruit_count > 0))
```